# NullPointerException when using AwsDefaultClientBuilder

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "software.amazon.awssdk.identity.spi.IdentityProviders.toBuilder()" because the return value of "software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.config.SdkClientConfiguration.option(software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.config.ClientOption)" is null
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.builder.AwsDefaultClientBuilder.finalizeChildConfiguration(AwsDefaultClientBuilder.java:215)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.syncClientConfiguration(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:188)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DefaultDynamoDbClientBuilder.buildClient(DefaultDynamoDbClientBuilder.java:55)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DefaultDynamoDbClientBuilder.buildClient(DefaultDynamoDbClientBuilder.java:27)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.build(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:155)
    at org.mattei.service.DynamoDbService.<init>(DynamoDbService.java:25)
    at org.mattei.Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

I am getting this exception and i cant figure out why..I am trying to use DynamoDbEnhancedAsyncClient and getting this exception, I am not sure which option is missing after debugging..checked many aws docs, yt, etc..tia

```
    static String tableName = "rules";
   static final TableSchema<Rule> TABLE_SCHEMA = TableSchema.fromBean(Rule.class);
DynamoDbAsyncClient dynamoDbAsyncClient = DynamoDbAsyncClient.create();
    DynamoDbEnhancedAsyncClient enhancedClient =
            DynamoDbEnhancedAsyncClient.builder()
                    .dynamoDbClient(dynamoDbAsyncClient)
                    .build();
       DynamoDbAsyncTable<Rule> TABLE = enhancedClient.table(tableName, TABLE_SCHEMA);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a null pointer exception from `AwsDefaultClientBuilder` returning null. This is caused by the SDK trying to acquire access keys to allow your code permissions to do what it needs to do. But you don't have any access keys in the permission chain so it returns null.

AWS credentials provider chain that looks for credentials in this order:

- Environment Variables - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY (RECOMMENDED since they are recognized by all the AWS SDKs and CLI except for .NET), or AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY (only recognized by Java SDK)
- Java System Properties - aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey
- Web Identity Token credentials from the environment or container
- Credential profiles file at the default location (~/.aws/credentials) shared by all AWS SDKs and the AWS CLI
- Credentials delivered through the Amazon EC2 container service if AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" environment variable is set and security manager has permission to access the variable,
- Instance profile credentials delivered through the Amazon EC2 metadata service

Comment: That exception message doesn't mention credentials at all. If it is truly a credentials issue, then AWS needs to do better.

Comment: In the first line it mentions `IdentityProviders`. We love feedback, which you can provide easily on the documentation, link at the bottom.

Comment: :shrug: I'm not the OP, and I do most of my work with Python, where we get messages like "Unable to locate credentials". And TBH, I've spent far too much of my time in recent weeks submitting feedback to AWS over the past few weeks, especially about the intrusive "Q" popups in the documentation. But really, it shouldn't require feedback to recognize that isn't a "customer obsessed" error message.